# How can I access storage/app/public/ in Laravel without using Symlink?

Tags: php, laravel

Can we access the **storage/app/public/** path in Laravel without using **symbolic link (Symlink)**? So that I can load or view my resources directly.

example:

```
 Static String baseUrlImg = 'domain.com/storage/app/public/image/item.png';
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing files in storage/app/public/ directly in Laravel without using a symbolic link (symlink) is not the standard approach, as Laravel's public/ directory is intended to be the document root for your application, providing direct access to assets. However, if you must access these files without using a symlink, you could consider a few alternative approaches:

Custom Route to Serve Files:
You can create a custom route and controller method to serve files from the storage/app/public directory. This method reads the requested file from the storage path and returns it as a response.

Example:

Route definition:

```
Route::get('/storage/{filename}', 'StorageController@getFile')->where('filename', '.*');
```

Controller method:

```
public function getFile($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path('app/public/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
}
```

This method involves additional overhead for each request, as PHP must read and serve the file content, which might be less efficient than serving files directly through the web server.

Direct Web Server Configuration:

If you have control over your web server configuration, you could configure it to serve the contents of storage/app/public/ as if they were located in your public/ directory. This approach requires careful configuration to ensure security and proper access control.

For Apache:

You might use an Alias directive in your Apache site configuration:

```
Alias "/storage" "/path/to/laravel/storage/app/public"
<Directory "/path/to/laravel/storage/app/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For Nginx:

You could use a location block in your Nginx site configuration:

```
location /storage/ {
    alias /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Adjusting the Document Root:

As an alternative, consider adjusting the document root of your web server to point to Laravel's public/ directory if it's not already set up this way. This won't directly solve the problem of accessing storage/app/public without a symlink, but it's a reminder to ensure your setup follows Laravel's intended structure.

Each of these methods has its own set of implications, especially concerning security and performance. It's crucial to ensure that any method used to serve files from storage does not inadvertently expose sensitive files or data. The symlink approach is recommended in most cases because it aligns with Laravel's design and security model. If you choose an alternative method, make sure to carefully control access to your files.

Comment: Nika what if the URL is called via Mobile API or other third-party application directly? it is still 404.